# Teradata: Is there a way to generate DDL from a view or select statement?

Tags: teradata

I am using a global application user account to access database A.  This user account does not have permissions to modify database A's schema (ie, create tables, modify tables, etc).  This user also has access to database B, but only views.  I need to run SQL to feed data from a view in database B into a table in database A.

In a perfect world, I would be able to use this SQL:

`create database_a.mytable as (select * from database_b) with no data`

However, the user can't create tables in database A.  If I could get the DDL of the select statement then I could log in under my personal account (which doesn't have any access to database B) and run the DDL in database A to create the table.

The only other option is to manually write the SQL, but I don't want to do that, especially since this view I am wanting to copy has many columns of varying data types and sizes.

**Edit:** I may be getting closer.  I just experimented with this:

`show (select * from database_b.myview)`

However, it generated the DLL of every single table that is used in the view itself, as well as the definition for the view.  This doesn't really help me since I just want the schema of the select statement itself.  In other words, I need what would be generated if I were to use the `create table as` statement mentioned above.

**Edit for Rob:** Perhaps "DDL" was the wrong term to use.  Using `show view db.myview` just shows the definition of the view, not the schema it represents.  In my above example of `create table as`, I show how you can create a table that mimics the schema of a result set returned in a select.  It generates a DDL on the back end for creating a table and then executes that DDL to actually create the table.  You can then say `show table db.newtable` and see the new table's DDL.  I want to get *that* DDL directly from a select statement so that I can copy it, log out of the app account, into my personal account, and then execute the DDL to create the table.

This is only to save me the headache of having to type out the DDL manually by hand to save time and reduce typing errors, especially since the source view has so many columns.  That said, I think hitting up the DBA or writing some snazzy stored procedure to do dynamic stuff would be a bit over the top for my needs.  I think there has to be a way to get the DDL for creating a table schema directly from a select statement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Generate DDL Statements for objects:**

```
SHOW TABLE {DatabaseB}.{Table1};
SHOW VIEW {DatabaseB}.{View1};
```

**Breakdown of columns in a view:**

```
HELP VIEW {DatabaseB}.{View1};
```

However, without the ability to create the object in the target database `DatabaseA` your don't have much leverage. Obviously, if the object already existed `INSERT INTO SELECT ... FROM DatabaseB.Table1` or `MERGE INTO` would be options that you already explored.

**Alternative Solution**

Would it be possible to have a stored procedure created that dynamically created the table based on the view name that is provided? The global application account would simply need privilege to execute the procedure. Generally the user creating the stored procedure would need the permissions to perform the actions contained within the stored procedure. (You have some additional flexibility with this in Teradata 13.10.)

There are some caveats with this approach. You are attempting to materialize views that could reference anywhere from hundreds to billions of records. These aren't simple 1:1 views that are put on top of the target tables. Trying to determine the required space in the target database to materialize the view will be difficult. Performance can and will vary depending on the complexity of the view and the data volumes. This will not be a fast-path or data block optimized operation.

As a DBA, I would be concerned with this approach being taken on by a global application account without fully understanding the intent. I trust you have an open line of communication with the DBA(s) involved for supporting this system. I'm sure there are reasons for your madness that can't be disclosed here.

**Possible Solution - VOLATILE TABLE**

Unless the implicit privilege for CREATE TABLE has been revoked from the global application account this solution should work.

Volatile tables do not require perm space. There table definitions persist for the duration of the session and any data inserted into them relies on the spool space of the user who instantiated it.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE {Global Application UserID}.{TableA_Copy} AS 
(
   SELECT *
     FROM {DatabaseB}.{TableA}
)
 WITH NO DATA
   NO PRIMARY INDEX
   ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

SHOW TABLE {Global Application UserID}.{TableA_Copy};
```

I opted to use a Teradata 13.10 feature called `NO PRIMARY INDEX`. By default, `CREATE TABLE` AS will take the first column of the `SELECT` statement and make it the `PRIMARY INDEX` of the table. This could lead to skewing and perm space issues in your testing depending on the data demographics. You can specify an explicit `PRIMARY INDEX` on your own as you understand the underlying data. (See the DDL manuals for details on the syntax if you're uncertain.)

The use of `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` for the intent of this example is probably extraneous. But in reality if you popped any data into that table for testing this clause would be beneficial in Teradata mode as the data would otherwise be lost immediately after the `CREATE TABLE` or any other data manipulation was performed against the volatile table.

Comment: I update my answer with details.  Let me know if what I am wanting to do cannot be done.

Comment: Added second potential solution. I think the stored procedure approach is too cumbersome in light of the newest solution.

Comment: Amazing!  It worked perfectly.  I do have to edit a bit of the DDL, but you have no idea how much time this is going to save me.  Of course, I could have done it 30 times in the time it took me to post my question and get the answer, but this is resusable for the future.  Thanks!